# How to access PostgreSQL and MongoDB databases in wolkenkit

Tags: wolkenkit

I am not able to connect with MongoDB and PostgreSQL. I am using the command below:

```
docker exec -it todomvc-mongodb mongo -user wolkenkit -p 576085646aa24f4670b929f0c47032ebf149e48f admin.
```

It shows the following result:

```
2018-08-14T11:48:20.592+0000 E QUERY [thread1] Error: Authentication failed. : –
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried to reproduce your issue. What I have done:

- I cloned the [wolkenkit-todomvc sample application](https://github.com/thenativeweb/wolkenkit-todomvc).
- I started it using `wolkenkit start`.

This gave me the (randomly created) shared key `4852f4430d67990c28354b6fafae449c4f82e9ab` (please note that this value is different each time you run `wolkenkit start`, unless you set it explicitly to a value of your choice, so YMMV).

Then I tried:

```
$ docker exec -it todomvc-mongodb mongo -user wolkenkit -p 4852f4430d67990c28354b6fafae449c4f82e9ab admin
```

It actually doesn't work. The reason for this is that the parameter `-user` does not exist, it either has to be `-u` or `--username`. If you run:

```
$ docker exec -it todomvc-mongodb mongo -u wolkenkit -p 4852f4430d67990c28354b6fafae449c4f82e9ab admin
```

Then, things work as expected.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks Golo. It should be handled at my side. Thank your support. And how we can connect with postgress ?

Comment: We are able to login through : docker exec -it todomvc-postgres psql wolkenkit wolkenkit